# Python error expected an indented block at the end of program file, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python, for-loop

I get the error as expected an indented block, at the end most line. i am simply using nested for loops to implement a logic and I am unable to understand what is wrong here, as far as I know i have indented everything with one tab in the for loop

```
# Program to show various ways to read and 
# write data in a file. 
file1 = open("testcases.h","w")
file1.write("//Do not modify, this is an auto-generated file\n")
file1.write("\n")
file1.close() #to change file access modes 
    
for byte in range(100, 110):
    for bw in range(0,2):
        for nss in range(0, 2):
            for mcs in range(0,10):
                #file1 = open("testcases.h","a") 
                #rate_flags = 0
                #rate_flags = mcs | ((nss << 4) | (bw << 11) | 1<<26        
                #counter = 0
                #file1.write("//Test case no. %s \n" %counter)
                #L = ["{\n"]        
                # \n is placed to indicate EOL (End of Line)  
                #file1.writelines(L)
```

Comment: Why have you commented out those lines

Comment: @Uncias he reason I started commenting everything is because I was getting an invalid syntax for this assignment counter = 0, so now the same code uncommneted code gives an invalid syntax. What could be wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your codes ends with a for loop but there is no code inside the for loop as it all commented out. add either `pass` or `...` (ellipsis) inside the for loop if you don't want it to do anything for now.

Final result:

```
# Program to show various ways to read and 
# write data in a file. 
file1 = open("testcases.h","w")
file1.write("//Do not modify, this is an auto-generated file\n")
file1.write("\n")
file1.close() #to change file access modes 
    
for byte in range(100, 110):
    for bw in range(0,2):
        for nss in range(0, 2):
            for mcs in range(0,10):
                pass # <------------------------- Now the final for loop is not empty
                #file2 = open("testcases.h","a") 
                #rate_flags = 0
                #rate_flags = mcs | ((nss << 4) | (bw << 11) | 1<<26        
                #counter = 0
                #file1.write("//Test case no. %s \n")
                #L = ["{\n"]        
                # \n is placed to indicate EOL (End of Line)  
                #file1.writelines(L)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, now it works with the pass but the reason I started commenting everything is because I was getting an invalid syntax for this assignment counter = 0, so now teh same code uncommneted counter = 0 gives an invalid syntax. What could be wrong

Comment: @Dspguysam The ```counter=0``` line gave you an error because the line before it is missing a closing bracket: ```rate_flags = mcs | ((nss << 4) | (bw << 11) | 1<<26```. You need to add it ''')''' and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends in a for loop, with nothing inside the loop itself.

All you need to do is put some filler code in that last for loop, or take remove the comments.

Code should look like this at the end:

```
for byte in range(100, 110):
    for bw in range(0,2):
        for nss in range(0, 2):
            for mcs in range(0,10):
                pass
```